# C++ Seg Fault at end of function. Reference line = closing brace

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault, curly-braces, strcpy

In conclusion: Thanks so much everyone! All the responses posted below were correct. The initial error was me forgetting to leave room for the NULL terminator. Strcpy() is a dangerous function because when I used it, it didn't know when the end of the 'string' was. Therefore, strcpy() grabbed to much data and overwrote the return address.

EDIT: added more code from the program

SOLVED: Honestly, my initial implementation was crap. I don't even know why I wrote swap that way if I wanted to swap out elements of the array. (At the time, each element only had the a char array in it. So I was able to get away with the old implementation). I have re-written it to:

```
void swap(ArrayElement list[], int index1, int index2) {
     ArrayElement temp;
     temp = list[index1];
     list[index1] = list[index2];
     list[index2] = temp;
}
```

---

I'm having problems with a segmentation fault at the end of the following function.

```
struct ArrayElement {
    char data[SIZE_OF_ELEMENT];
    // Implemented this way so that I can expand to multiple values later on
}

//In main:
ArrayElement* list = new ArrayElement[NUM_OF_ELEMENTS];

void swap(ArrayElement list[], int index1, int index2) {
     char temp[SIZE_OF_ELEMENT];
     strcpy(temp, list[index2].data);
     strcpy(list[index2].data, list[index1].data);
     strcpy(list[index1].data, temp);
}
```

The error is a segmentation fault at line 45, which is the ending curly brace of the function. This was compiled using g++. I used gbd to try and debug it and everything works correctly until it hits the curly brace.

I can give more code from the program if it is needed. I don't want to post the entire thing because this is for a class.

Comment: `std::swap(list[index2].data, list[index1].data)` would this work for you, just out of curiosity.

Comment: You should show at least the context where you're calling the function and what `ArrayElement` is ...

Comment: have you tried your debugger?

Comment: @JimBalter - Only if `.data` is an array. If it is a `char*`, your suggestion is buggy.

Comment: @Robᵩ Yup ... I wrote hastily.

Comment: @AndersK Yes, see "I used gbd to try and debug it ..."

Comment: Ok, this is C++ ... you shouldn't be using raw char arrays.

Comment: I needed to make an array of "strings" should I not have used char arrays for this?

Comment: With a string in C++, one usually means [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Comment: @user1477320 You should use `std::string` for representing strings in C++, An array of strings should either be represented as `std::vector<std::string>` (or `std::array<std::string>` with C++11).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My best guess is, the string at `list[index2].data` is larger than `temp[]` and by copying, you overwrote the stack and the return address.

Try inserting a test for the length:

```
#include <iostream>

...
int n = strlen(list[index2].data);
std::cerr << "len=" << n << ", SIZE_OF_ELEMENT=" << SIZE_OF_ELEMENT << std::endl;
```

and see, if `n` (list[index2].data) is larger than `SIZE_OF_ELEMENT`

Comment: You were right. I got len=240 and SIZE_OF_ELEMENT=30. I don't see how this would be. (I've added more code to the original post). This implementation has worked before using my own test data. When I used the file from the instructor this error started occuring. I will rewrite swap to make temp be an ArrayElement object and use '=' to do the swapping... lets see if it works :)

Comment: Thank you in helping me solve my problem. If you want to read a conclusion of what was wrong, I added it to the top of the original post.

Answer (score 2):

`strcpy` is a hazardous function. If the length of the input string is `SIZE_OF_ELEMENT` or more, you will write past the end of your `temp` array. If you must use a fixed size array as the output array in `strcpy`, you should test that the `strcpy` will work before using the function.

Even better is to switch from using `char` arrays to `std::string`.

Comment: Thank you in helping me solve my problem. If you want to read a conclusion of what was wrong, I added it to the top of the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Is data defined like this `char data[SOME_CONSTANT]`? If so then are you sure that SIZE_OF_ELEMENT is large enough? You are remembering the NULL terminator too, *right*?

If in ArrayElement data is defined like this `char *data;` and is allocated with malloc at a later time then are you *sure* that index1 has a buffer large enough for the data in index2 and vice versa? Again, you are remembering the NULL terminator too, *right*?

Comment: I did forget the NULL terminator. That was the initial error. Thank you in helping me solve my problem. If you want to read a conclusion of what was wrong, I added it to the top of the original post.